# Get value of Attribute using file_get_contents

Tags: php, domdocument, file-get-contents

i want to the value of the attribute href from a specific link.

the html code where i want to fetch the value looks like this:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@xy.com">Some link</a>
```

i want to have the inner href (mailto:mail@xy.com) but i get the value of the link (Some link).

**Here is the code:**

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($content);


$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
    if( strpos($node->getAttribute('href'), 'mailto') !== false ) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $node->nodeValue . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($content);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
    $nodehref = $node->getAttribute('href');
    if( strpos($nodehref, 'mailto') !== false ) {
        echo "<tr><td>$nodehref</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: wow - surprised that it is such an easy fix! i didnt get the point, that getAttribute already fetches the inner value of it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use a substring to the current value you have:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . substr($node->getAttribute('href'),7)  . '</td></tr>';
```

I don't like the magic number like 7, but is the length of "mailto:". Replace with a variable if you wish.

Comment: what about `substr($node->getAttribute('href'),"mailto:".length)`

Comment: You can do that. But use `strlen('mailto')` instead.

Comment: O yes, of course, I just answered a JS question that's why automatically I used .length, but you got the idea

Comment: @FelippeDuarte This more of a nice addition, that could be a comment, than it is an answer to the actual problem of getting the incorrect data (because of an incorrect method call). Right?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to access is the `href` attribute, the one that you're already using correctly as an argument for `strpos()`. However in your echo you're using the value of the `<a>` element (i.e. `nodeValue()`). W3CSchool has some [short information](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) on this stuff that may be worth reading.

This should work:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
    if( strpos($node->getAttribute('href'), 'mailto') !== false ) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $node->getAttribute('href') . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just call `$node->getAttribute('href')` once and store it in a variable.